# Schemas server with Swagger and NestJs. how can i add this schemas example?

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

How can I add this option to my swagger documentation with NestJs?
The only possibility I found was `addServer()`, but it doesn't leave it as an example, it uses the server. The only possibility I found was `addServer()`, but it doesn't leave it as an example, it uses the server. [example what am I trying to add]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGBaM.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

without a code example with which you are trying to achieve this I can only assume you are trying to setup the swagger docs via DocumentBuilder class in your `main.ts`

You can use the addServer() method to achieve what you want

```js
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Your API')
    .setDescription('API documentation')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('example')
    .addServer('http://localhost', 'HTTP') // HTTP scheme
    .addServer('https://localhost', 'HTTPS') // HTTPS scheme
    .build();

    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);

    SwaggerModule.setup('openapi', app, document);
```